# Front end member uploader

Tags: frontend, upload, member

Hi I'm fairly new still to CraftCMS. I built one website with it a few years ago and have tinkered with it ever since and I do like it a lot. What I've been asked to do is create a website directory for front end users to create an account and add their own content. It sounds like it might be beyond my ability though. Normally I develop in Wordpress (building bespoke themes and scripting custom fields) but even with something like this I would still resort to a plugin. Is this something that can be done fairly straight forward with Craft or do you know of a plugin for Craft that would achieve this?

Each account should get approval by admin before going live. They can then upload a profile picture, bio, gallery of images, text, video, and pdf and change password, email and other user details. It should also have it's own interface styling rather than Craft CMS back end interface. I have attached a crude example of what I have been asked to look into.

If you could give me a few pointers as to where I should look to see if it's something I could take on then that would be a great help.

Thanks very much.[image]

Answer (score 0):

At a basic level, front-end user account management is definitely something that can be done with Craft Pro natively.

There's a knowledge base article on the subject here: https://craftcms.com/knowledge-base/front-end-user-accounts

> Each account should get approval by admin before going live.

Also possible natively, with the "Suspect users by default" user setting (Settings->Users->Settings in the Craft control panel.

[image]

I'm not saying you won't have to use a plugin (whether it's [already built](https://plugins.craftcms.com) or a [custom-built one](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/extend/#modules-vs-plugins)), but depending on your specific requirements, you might be able to get way with natively functionality.